# Dropdown menus not appearing in correct place for Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have created some drop down menus (which appear if you hover over their parent's link), the drop down menus simply contain links; nothing special.

They work absolutely fine when using Google Chrome (under their parent), but they always appear towards the far left hand side of the screen when using Mozilla Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be happening?

**Google Chrome:**

[image: Google Chrome Working]

**Mozilla Firefox:**

[image: Mozilla Firefox Not Working]

**Drop down HTML inspect example:**

[image: Drop down HTML inspect example]

**Relevant CSS:**

```
/* Sub menu styles */
#headermenu td.hasSubMenu ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 200px;
    left: -999em;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #89B0F1;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #000000;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #252B76;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu:hover ul {
    left: 0px;
    top: auto;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #252B76;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li:hover a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: please dont use tables for layouts

Comment: @ErikMes It was the only way to achieve what I needed to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seemingly resolved this myself by tweaking a few things.

Instead of hiding the drop down menus by pushing them off the page (using `left: -999em;`), I'm now using `display: none;` and then using `display: block;` when it's hovered over. This, however meant that the drop down was pushed 10 pixels to the right of it's parent; which didn't look right, to counter this I tried using `left: 0px;`, but it caused the problem with Firefox rendering the drop down way to the left to reappear. I tried `margin-left: -10px;` and it worked.

**So the CSS I'm now using looks like this:**

```
/* Sub menu styles */
#headermenu td.hasSubMenu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #89B0F1;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #000000;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #252B76;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #252B76;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#headermenu td.hasSubMenu li:hover a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider placing the dropdown menu list inside of the same div or container that contains the menu item. Position relative the menu item and use absolute positioning to push the dropdown menu beneath the menu item container. I find this to be a much more reliable method. So for example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    Menu Text
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:0;">
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu Item #1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu Item #2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu Item #3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will have to adjust the bottom and left values to suite your needs.